# How to Save and Get ObservableCollection from IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am populating an ObservableCollection of a custom class type. I have the need to save this collection when the application closes and reload it when the main application page is navigated to. I am unsure of the best process.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<History> Items { get; set; }

public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<History>();
        HistoryListBox.ItemsSource = Items; //HistoryListBox displays the Items
    }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ... populate HistoryListBox from Saved data? ....
    }

private async void RunPerformanceTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ... run some processes ...

        PopulateHistoryListBox();
    }

private void PopulateHistoryListBox()
    {
        Items.Add(new History { ConnectionType = ConnectionTypeResultTextBlock.Text, DateTime = DateTime.Now, ConnectionLatency = NetworkLatencyResultTextBlock.Text, ConnectionSpeed = NetworkSpeedResultTextBlock.Text });
    }
```

History.cs

```
public string ConnectionType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ConnectionSpeed
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ConnectionLatency
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

so what would be the best way to save the ObservableCollection to IsolatedStorage and then Retrieve it?

Comment: I tend to load and save non-vm types like List<T>.  Then create an observable collection from that when deseiralizing--which the intent of MVVM.  I usually use Json.NET for ease of use and the ability to read the saved data if needed.

Comment: I believe I've used the XMLSerializer before but I cannot remember how or find my solution. Since these datatypes in the `History.cs` are nothing fancy, what do you recommend? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest embracing MVVM.  Create a View Model class and move `Items` to there.  Then bind the `Items` property to the `ListBox` in the XAML.

Generally state is loaded in the `Page`'s `Loaded` event handle and saved in the `Unloaded` event.  But, depending on how the app navigates from page to page, you might want to load state in `OnNavigatedTo` and save state in `OnNavigatedFrom`.  Load would generally create the view model and load it from isolated storage, and the save would save its state to isolated storage.  For example:

```
private MainViewModel MainViewModel;
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
    using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        try
        {
            if (iso.FileExists("AppState.date"))
            {
                using (var stream = iso.OpenFile("AppState.dat", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    string text;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                    var history = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<History>>(text);
                    MainViewModel.Items = history;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            // TODO: log
        }
    }
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = iso.OpenFile("AppState.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(stream.Length);
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MainViewModel.Items));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            // TODO: log
        }
    }
}
```

This, of course, assumes you've added the Json.NET package to your project.

To aid in design, you could instead create the view model within the XAML (so you have something to bind to in design).  For example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
```

In the constructor for MainViewModel, construct debug state, if necessary.

Then, you can initialize the view model to something other than a "debug" state in the `Loaded` event handler or `OnNavigatedTo`, for example:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MainViewModel = (MainViewModel) DataContext;
    //...
```